# How to set up a private blockchain using EOS?

Tags: eosio-code, private-blockchain, eosio.system

I have read that it is possible to set up a private blockchain using EOS. Can anyone help me to understand how to set up a private chain using EOS.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Simply you can do it by [this link](https://medium.com/@kaloliya/step-by-step-guide-to-set-up-your-private-eos-network-eosio-6d80c30dd520).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever you set up a local testnet node or run nodeos on your home computer, you are creating a new EOS chain. What matters is how you choose to connect it to other nodes to decentralise the system.

If you want a private blockchain for, say, your office building, then you would set up several instances of nodeos in the office and connect them to each other using your LAN p2p addresses.

Comment: Is there are any tutorial so that i can follow  and learn.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can create a private blockchain take a look to this tutorial : https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

this tutorial written by EOS developer. https://medium.com/@kaloliya/step-by-step-guide-to-set-up-your-private-eos-network-eosio-6d80c30dd520

Answer (score 2):

EOSIO Private network tutorial by EOS Costa Rica:

https://guide.eoscostarica.io/docs/tutorials/private-network-installation